# Soft 404, Fetch and Render showing js bundle temporarily unreachable

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, seo, asp.net-bundling

We recently launched a new page to our site.  Previously our whole site has been in classic asp and this page is an angular SPA with asp.net on the backend.

Since the launch of the [new page](https://www.containerandpackaging.com/item/J048) our amount of soft 404s have dramatically increased with most being on this page.

[image]

After running the google fetch and render 20 times, there were two instances when the JS bundle (bundled by asp.net) returned as temporarily unreachable for the google bot.

[image: Temporarily unreachable]

I've gone through the IIS logs pretty closely searching for these bundles during the time I was testing and they all returned a 200 status code.

What can I do to debug this further?  Why would the bundle be temporarily unreachable?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014169/asp-net-mvc-4-bundling-and-minification-404-issues-on-64-bit-iis-7-5-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686495/microsoft-bundles-return-404-occasionally-on-deployment-or-in-development ?

Comment: Good finds!  I am trying them now.  Thanks!